# Difference between client certificates and certificate pinning, Do I need both?

Tags: security, ssl, asp.net-web-api, xamarin, ssl-certificate

I have a .net WEB API publicly exposed and also a Xamarin Forms App which uses the API, the app needs to be extremely secure due to the data it manages.

I will create an HTTP Certificate for the WEB API.
The Xamarin Forms app will have a login/password to validate against a local Active Directory. via a /token endpoint, and using an Authorize attribute on all endpoints to assure that every HTTP call has the bearer token in it, I implemented that using this:

I based my implementation on this one:
http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

Additionally the customer has asked us for Client Certificate Authentication, I dont understand how this totally works.
1. I need to add a certificate to the Xamarin Project, right? How do I Add it? How do I generate it?
2. In the Web API I need to validate each http call has the certificate attached.
I found this but not sure if it will work:
http://www.razibinrais.com/secure-web-api-with-client-certificate/

However when investigating this, I also found something about certificate pinning, which is basically security but the other way around, it means the Xamarin APP will validate if the server certificate is associated with the right server (or something like that), so there is no way of a MAN IN THE MIDDLE Attack.
I found how to implement it here:
https://thomasbandt.com/certificate-and-public-key-pinning-with-xamarin

Question is: 
1. Do I need both ?

Something else that I should research for on this journey?

Comment: @Julian: why did you remove the Xamarin and ASP .NET tags? The question is clearly related to Xamarin and ASP .NET (Web API) as well.

Comment: that is correct.!

Comment: This is about SSL certificates. It could be any app. The same for asp.net.  The tags should describe the problem, not the environment. This is not an xamarin/asp.net problem.

Comment: @Julian: The [help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) state nothing about that? It says the following: You should re-tag questions when:

- You are adding valuable information to the question by doing so
- You are replacing obscure or difficult to understand tags with well-known and popular tags that are appropriate for the question.

Comment: @tim https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280173/should-tags-primarily-be-used-for-categorization-or-searchability

Comment: I see currently there are more questions in one question, with different topics. Splitting was a better solution IMO.

Comment: For example, the title had nothing to do with xamarin or asp.net. This is too broad.

Comment: @Julian: you are correct, this is probably why I was confused about the tags. Thanks for pointing to that link though!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Certificate pinning and Client Certificate Authentication are 2 very different things. Certificate pinning makes sure your app is talking to the server it expects to talk to. It also prevents eavesdropping, which is known as a 'Man in the middle' attack. I just recently wrote an article about this [on my blog](https://tim.klingeleers.be/2017/04/21/security-xamarin-certificate-pinning/).

Client Certificate Authentication works the other way around. It adds an extra layer of security so your server can be sure only clients that have the certificate can communicate successfully with it. However, since apps can be decompiled without a lot of effort, this client certificate can 'easily' be obtained by a malicious user. So this isn't a silver bullet.

From my experience, Client Certificate Authentication is often used in enterprise apps, when there is an Enterprise Mobility Management solution in place (eg. Mobile Iron or Microsoft Intune or others), where the EMM solution can push the certificates to the users device out of band.

Should you use both? That really depends on the requirements of your customer, since they mitigate 2 very different problems.

The Web API link you included looks like it should do the server job properly at first sight. This article also includes how to generate a client certificate with a Powershell command.

**Generating a client side certificate:**

- Use the Powershell command in [the article that you referenced in your question.](http://www.razibinrais.com/secure-web-api-with-client-certificate/)
- Otherwise, [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mtigas/952344) might help you on your way.

**Installation:**

- Add the certificate file to each platform specific project as a resource. This is usually done in the form of a .p12 file.

**Usage:**

- That all depends on which HttpClient you are using.
- If you use the provided Web API solution, you should add the certificate contents as a `X-ARR-ClientCert` header with each request.